# Given some positive integer $n$, how many general pentagonal numbers are there smaller than it?

Tags: combinatorics, summation

General pentagonal numbers are given by:

$$p(t) = \frac{3t^2 - t}{2},$$

where $t \in \mathbb{Z}$. Note that for all $t$, $p(t) \geq 0$.

For some $n > 0$, how many pentagonal numbers are there less than $n$?

Comment: Your title just asks about how many pentagonal numbers are smaller than $n$ while the body asks about how many it takes to sum up to more than $n$.  The first yields a quadratic.  Which are you interested in?

Comment: @RossMillikan Well, I thought that knowing how many it would take to sum up to $n$ would be the same as asking how many there are below $n$? Hmm, actually, I am not sure that these are the same any more. I think what I have to do is not sum the pentagonal numbers, but the spacing between them. This spacing should sum to approximately $n$?

Comment: @RossMillikan P.S. please don't answer the question asked in the title directly (at least not yet!) :)

Comment: I am working on the one in the body.

Comment: @RossMillikan sweet, but I might be changing the body all up to reflect my newest thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general pentagonal number for some input integer $x$ is:
        $$ p(x) = \frac{3x^2 - x}{2} $$

In general, $p(k) < p(-k)$ for some $k > 0$. This is because the parabola $p(x)$ is slightly shifted in the positive $x$ direction on the x-axis, and we are interested in integer inputs for $x$, so integer $-1$ will correspond to a slightly higher location on the left branch of the parabola than integer $1$'s corresponding point on the right branch.

So, let us focus on the sequence of numbers generated by the integers $k$ such that $1 \leq k$ and:
        $$ p'(k) = \frac{3k^2 + k}{2} $$

We want to find $k$ such that:
   \begin{align*}
    &\quad n - p'(k) = 0 \\
    &\quad n - \frac{3k^2 + k}{2} = 0\\
    &\Rightarrow k = \frac{-(1/2) \pm \sqrt{(1/4) - 4(3/2)(n)}}{3}
   \end{align*}
    We end up getting two solutions for $k$ anyway, and we can just accept both. After all, the negative $k$ will just end up giving us the number we would have gotten if we plugged in $-k$ into $p'(k)$, which would correspond to the $p(k)$ pentagonal number. Dropping the constants since as $n$ becomes large, they'll be dwarfed, we get:
        \begin{align*}
        2k &\approx 2\sqrt{4(3/2)(n)}{3} \\
           &\approx \sqrt{\frac{8}{3}n}
    \end{align*}
    Which is essentially what we are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Once $k$ is moderately large, $k^2$ will be rather small compared to $k^3$.  You can do fixed point iteration.  Start with $k_0=\sqrt[3]{2n}$, then iterate $k_{i+1}=\sqrt[3]{2n-k_i^2}$.  It will converge quickly.  As an example, if $k=100, n=5050$.  We get $k_0\approx 100.33$ and it converges quickly to $k=100$

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume the question in the title is what is wanted.

The pentagonal numbers form an increasing sequence:

$$p(1)<p(2)<p(3)<...<p(t)<...$$

If you want to find how many of these are smaller than $n$, you need to find the largest index $t$ such that:

$$p(1)<p(2)<p(3)<...<p(t)<n$$

Then we know that each of the pentagonal numbers $p(1)$ to $p(t)$ are smaller than $n$, and that all the remaining pentagonal numbers $p(t+1)$ etc are larger. The number of pentagonal numbers smaller than $n$ is then simply $t$ (because they are $p(1)$ to $p(t)$).

So what you need to find is the largest integer $t$ such that

$$p(t) = \frac{3t^2 - t}{2} < n$$

Note: If you want to include $p(0)=0$ in your count, just do the above and add $1$ to your answer.

Comment: the question asks how to approximate the cubic

Comment: @qwr See the comments above. Ross already answered the question in the body of the post. I'm concentrating on the question in the title of the post because the cubic is irrelevant to finding the answer to that question.